# Links invisible until hovered over

Tags: bug, design, css

For some reason, as of earlier today, the text of links in main’s homepage is no longer visible for me until after I’ve hovered over the link. Links to questions in a tag I follow do appear, however. On the flip-side, *everything* (link or not) is invisible in the Looking for More? box, the network navigation box, and the copyright box.

This does not seem to happen every time I load the page, but it happens pretty consistently if I reload rather than follow a link. It does not seem to apply to links in questions, even the links that are the same in both pages.

I am using Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m.

Comment: This happens to me occasionally in both FireFox and Chrome, and refreshing the page usually fixes it.

Comment: Yep, I had that yesterday in Chrome.

Comment: I had the same problem, but now it's gone. I'm guessing this is some caching issue, probably related to SE's CDN servers. It comes and goes.

Comment: @lisardggY Yeah, it hasn’t really affected me since like the day after I made this post.